# Bluetooh hci0: command 0x1009 tx timeout

Tags: bluetooth, kali-linux

I have a problem with kali linux boot proccess

I got this message when the system boot up

```
 bluetooth : hci0: command 0x1009 tx timeout
```

I have searched for a soultion for this problem over this site and on google and I didn't find any answer that works with me

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue with the following command `systemctl restart bluetooth`